# Mysql - inserting NULL values in datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am updating a entry in my form

while doing so i cleared the value in datetimepicker and proceeding

```
if (empty($_POST['dtp'])) {
$Dtp = NULL;
}
```

Then posting as

```
'dtp' => $Dtp
```

SQL echo is like

```
UPDATE tbl_dummy SET Id="3",dtp="",Remark="update1"
```

The error is

> 1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'dtp' at row 1

Kindly guide me to solve this and insert NULL value in db

Comment: Can you show us the php code that generates the sql ?

Comment: i highly suggest that you use prepared statements

Comment: @Akintunde Sure mate , i will learn to do so soon. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an unquoted literal `NULL` to MySQL.  MySQL does not know of your PHP's NULL type.

```
UPDATE tbl_dummy SET Id=3,dtp=NULL,Remark="update1"
```

Comment: yup i tried in phpmyadmin it works .

But if i give 

`$Dtp = NULL; it is coming as ""` If i give `$Dtp = "NULL";` or `$Dtp = 'NULL';` its coming as "NULL" . How to post as NULL

Comment: How do you generate SQL of UPDATE statement?

Comment: You can use a simple if condition in PHP. If the value is null run the query above and if not, run your query with values

Comment: @Naktibalda You mean how do i get that statement . if so , then the answer is i echoed the insert query and die after that . is that what you were asking mate?

Comment: No, you use some function or class to generate it. I want to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a variable of type `timestamp`, set it to NULL, then use the variable to set the value on `update`:

```
nulltimestamp = null

strSql = "update {table name}, set {columnname}=nulltimestamp where {your limiting comdition}"

execute strsql
```