# How to import datetime field coded with `NULL` keyword in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have a table like as shown below

[image]

Please note that I already referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131977/mysql-inserting-null-values-in-datetime-field) and it's not duplicate

When I try to upload the data in csv file using MySQL workbench, I am able to see that it ignores `rows with NULL values for datetime field`. Meaning it only copies rows 2,4 and 5

Please find the error message below

> - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'Date_entry' at row 1", 1292)

Please note that `Date_entry` is an index column

```
alter table dummy
      add index ADMISSIONS_IDX01 (Subject),
      add index ADMISSIONS_IDX02 (Date_entry);
```

Table definition is like this:

```
Subject MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Date_entry DATETIME,
```

In create statement, I have a line like as shown below

```
Date_entry= IF(@Date_entry='', NULL, @Date_entry),
```

Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: You can alter data_entry to accepts null values as a default value

Comment: Can you see the updated post? I have the `if clause to handle that`. Will it not work?

Comment: I updated my create statement as mentioned in answer but still I get the same error.

Comment: I think the issue from the index of date_entry. try to remove it

Comment: Actually its part of table definition. Aren't columns NULL Values allowed to be index?

Comment: Removing index doesn't help either @BassemSamir

Comment: Check mysqlworkbench in importing process and treat empty cells as null in case inserting rows.

Comment: @BassemSamir - This is the setting that I follow With ',' as a field separator, 'LF' or 'CR' or 'CR LF' as line separators, null and NULL word as SQL keyword = `YES` and enclose strings in `"`

Comment: There is no specific field to `treat empty cells`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201596/discussion-between-ssmk-and-bassem-samir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL version >=8.0 by default `local_infile` is `off`. To load you need to first enable it.

```
set global local_infile = on;

load data local infile 'E:so.csv' into table dummy
fields terminated by ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Subject,@Date_entry)
set Date_entry=if(@Date_entry='',null, @Date_entry) ;
```

It will insert the data. If it throws error then share the result of `sql_mode`.

`select @@sql_mode;`

**Note:** Make sure that the csv on `Date_entry` column is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format as MySQL does, btw in your csv it is not in db format. I have tested the above case in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Sure. Will respond in another 15 mins.. Looking forward to resolve this. Currently away from my desk

Comment: Hi, I have a question regarding the date format. Can't we modify the date format?. Because I have a data with a million rows.

Comment: Yes, you can. Make sure the date from csv is in same format

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
Subject MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Date_entry DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Comment: Can you see the updated post for `if` clause and let me know whether it is incorrect to use that way?

Comment: You should first initialize DateTime column to Null. otherwise defaults it Not Null. You can't set it to null by using the If condition.

Comment: Yeah, So I followed your `create statement` and I get the same error.

Comment: how you imported the csv file values?

Comment: With `,` as a field separator, `LF` as line separator, null and NULL word as SQL keyword = `YES` and enclose strings in `"`

Comment: replace your commas with semicolons and try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201588/discussion-between-ssmk-and-kushan-hansika).